# Frida (android) - why java.lang.StringBuilder append is not hooked

Tags: frida

I'm studying frida.

As an example, I simply created a string through the StringBuilder and append it.

I hooked "append" using "frida".

But it doesn't work.

```java
    String val;
    val = "Log Data....";
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder("LOG : ").append(val);
    log.append("[[");
    log.append("]]");
```

```js
Java.perform(function () {

    var StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
    var ctor = StringBuilder.$init.overload('java.lang.String');

    ctor.implementation = function (arg) {
        var log_arg = '';
        var result = ctor.call(this, arg);
        if (arg !== null) {
            log_arg = arg.toString();
        }

        console.log('new StringBuilder("' + log_arg + '");');
        return result;
    };

    var append = StringBuilder.append.overload('java.lang.String');


    append.implementation = function (arg) {
        var result = append.call(this, arg);
        var log_arg = '';
        if (result !== null) {
            log_arg = result.toString();
        }
        console.log('StringBuilder.append1(); => ' + log_arg);
        return result;
    };
});
```

Result :
new StringBuilder("LOG : ");

" Log Data....[[]] " -  I can't see the message....  Probably not hooking.

Comment: Instead of `append.call(this, arg);` I would have used `this.append(arg)`. Not sure if both versions are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your hook to append isn't hooking the instance that was initialized.

```
var ctor = StringBuilder.$init.overload('java.lang.String');
```

This is where you initialize and allocate, so you need to make the call here. 
Something more like

```
var append = ctor.implementation = function(arg)...
```

should work. But because StringBuilder has a ton of overloads to cover a ton of data types and it can get called a ton of times, it's much easier to simply hook its toString method so that you don't have to do any casting or write a ton of overloads.

```
const StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
 StringBuilder.toString.implementation = function () {
var res = this.toString();
var tmp = "";
if (res !== null){
    tmp = res.toString().replace("/n", "");
    console.log(tmp);
}

return res;
};
```

should hook the actual string that it will output.